# ListView with CursorAdapter is not refreshing even if I use swapCursor or changeCursor methods in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have two activities an initial with a Listview and a FAB and a second one with editText, Save and Clear Buttons.

I call the second one the activity for result I enter my values and click Save Button. My list is not refreshed **its displaying only the first element** and I did 
the following

**in the first activity**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
    if(requestCode==3)
    {

        player = mHelper.getPlayersByTeam(new_id);

        if(player!=null && player.getCount()>0)
        {
            playerdataAdapter = new PlayerAdapter(this, player);
            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listPlayers.setAdapter(playerdataAdapter);
            playerdataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            playerdataAdapter.swapCursor(mHelper.getPlayersByTeam(new_id));
        }

    }
```

What I am doing wrong here? why listview not displaying the refreshed data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your database if you retrieve the proper records